# About Partitions, Are They Just Glorified File Markers?

Tags: partitioning

Do files in a partition exist in their own section of the hard drive? Are they just glorified file markers that allow the computer to say "this is partition 1," "this is partition 2," etc.?

Comment: [Beginner Geek: Hard Disk Partitions Explained](http://www.howtogeek.com/184659/beginner-geek-hard-disk-partitions-explained/)

Answer (score 1):

**DISCLAIMER**:  Playing with partitions is a bad idea unless you know what you're doing.  Always have a backup of your data before playing with partitions.  I'm not responsible if you lose everything.  Now with that out of the way, on to your question...

Basically.  It's a way to break up the physical disk into groupings for different uses.

I'll use a farm analogy:  The hard drive as a whole is the lot of land you own.  It will contain everything, however with no structures, you can't really do anything (store data) right away.  You need to have at least 1 partition.  So you build a barn.  This is a primary partition.  In it you can store your stuff (data).  You could build this barn to take up the entire lot if you wanted to, and that's just fine.

However, you're a true farmer and have different types of stuff you want to store.  So we'll say the barn takes up 1/4 of your lot.  Where do we put the horses?  They don't belong in the barn.  So we build a stable (another partition) and keep the horses and their gear in there.  Forgot about the chickens!  Let's build a chicken coop (yet another partition), that also takes up 1/4 of the lot.

These three buildings represent *primary* partitions.  A hard drive can only have up to 4 partitions.  However, we can get around this by using a *extended* partition.  Extended partitions let us take one of our 4 usable extensions and make as many *logical* partitions under it.  This will make sense in a minute.

Back to the analogy:  So 3/4ths of the partitions are used up.  What else can we do.  Ah, we farm land and need a place to put our tractors but also a place work on them!  This is where extended and logical partitions come into play.  We'll build a big shed that takes up the remaining 1/4th of th e lot.  This is our *extended* partition.  However, we can make as many distinct rooms (*logical*) partitions in it that we want.  So we'll have a big room for the tractors, a small shop area to work on various things with, and for giggles, a bathroom.

Recap:  We now have 6 partitions on our drive: 3 primary partitions and 1 extended partition which is made up of 3 logical partitions.  In Windows, this could possibly show up as drives C: - H: (or maybe C:, E-I: if you have a dvd drive).  Linux would give you /sda1 - /sda6 (sd being physical media for all intents and purposes, a is the physical drive, 1-6 is the partition number).

[Here's](http://www.howtogeek.com/184659/beginner-geek-hard-disk-partitions-explained/) another explanation that may help you out as well.  Also, I've included a visual example that may make more sense.

[image: Visual example]

Comment: This is a decent analogy, but note that the 4-partition limit is a feature of the old [Master Boot Record (MBR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) partitioning system. Most modern Macs and computers that shipped with Windows 8 and later use the newer [GUID Partition Table (GPT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) partitioning system, which has a default limit of 128 partitions (and that limit can be raised), so GPT has no need of, and does not support, extended and logical partitions. There are other schemes, too, but MBR and GPT are the most common.